# LuaTeX error: "Unable to read environment locale:exit now."

Tags: luatex

This is the output from LaTeX (MWE is at the end of this post):

> Running `LaTeX' on`luatex_test' with ``lualatex --jobname=luatex_test  -file-line-error   -interaction=nonstopmode "\input" luatex_test.tex''
>   Unable to read environment locale:exit now.

If I set TeX engine to be `latex` instead of `lualatex` in Emacs (I use version 25.1 (9.0)), it completes compilation. Also, the compilation completes if I call `lualatex` from the terminal.

Running `locale` in Emacs's shell gives:

> LANG="en_DE.UTF-8"
>   LC_COLLATE="C"
>   LC_CTYPE="C"
>   LC_MESSAGES="C"
>   LC_MONETARY="C"
>   LC_NUMERIC="C"
>   LC_TIME="C"
>   LC_ALL=

My MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Test compilation with luatex.
\end{document}
%%% Local Variables:
%%% mode: latex
%%% TeX-engine: luatex
%%% TeX-master: t
%%% End:
```

Which variable in Emacs do I need to customize?

Comment: I removed emacs tag as it happens if you run it directly in the shell, you could set LANG to be en_US.UTF-8

Comment: Raised as http://tug.org/pipermail/luatex/2017-June/006576.html

Comment: I even encountered this with `LANG="en_US.UTF-8"`. Answers in this thread suggest this should work (since it's nothing arcane like `en_DE`). Running `LANG= lualatex file.tex` works (empty value).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Changing the locale in my shell configuration file did not solve the problem. I found the reason here: [locale when launching Emacs.app on OS X](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/20427).

What did solve the problem was either adding `%%% eval: (setenv "LANG" "de_DE.UTF-8")` to my source file, as suggested in the comments, or adding this line to `.emacs` file: `(setenv "LANG" "en_US.UTF-8")`.

Answer (score 10):

I can confirm the same using cygwin texlive 2017 it is enough to set

```shell
export LANG="en_DE.UTF-8" 


lualatex testfile
```

to get

```
Unable to read environment locale:exit now.
```

You should raise this on the luatex list, or I could, although `en_DE` seems like a strange locale. German English?

Setting LANG to (say) `en_US` makes it work again.

It has been confirmed in the thread on the luatex list starting at

http://tug.org/pipermail/luatex/2017-June/006576.html

that it is by design that luatex quits on unknown locale, although they may try to make the error message a bit more helpful.

`en_DE` seems a strange value, depending on your operating system you may be able to use

```shell
locale -a
```

to list all the known values.

On my system

```shell
locale -a | grep en_
```

lists 37 `en_` variants, but `en_DE` is not one of them.

So I would not fix this in the emacs editor setup but rather set your locale to something other than `en_DE` in your shell.

Comment: How do I set it in Emacs? I have found `current-language-enivronment`, but it is already English.

Comment: @ted_kingdom `M-x setenv` I guess.

Comment: @ted_kingdom - Try adding something like this `%%% eval: (setenv "LANG" "de_DE.UTF-8")` in your .tex file in `Local Variables:` and reopen the file.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, `en_DE` means that in my system preferences I have Germany set as a region. Interestingly, on my other laptop where it says Sweden I do not have a problem with locale being `en_SE`. However, changing Germany to Sweden doesn't do the trick.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, Even if I set `export LANG="en_US"` I get error. Should I set any other variable as well?

Answer (score 0):

On my system, I have the `en_DK.utf8` locale set (except for `LC_TIME`, which is apparently set to `da_DK.utf8`). I also ran into this error.

Other answers here insinuate that it is the "weird" form of the chosen locale -- ie. there is really no such thing as danish/german english -- that is the cause of the problem. That is not correct, because in my case changing `en_DK` to `en_GB` did not help the problem.

Rather the issue is that one of the set locales is not installed. In my case, it was actually the `da_DK.utf8` locale that wasn't installed! You can check which locales are currently set with `locale` and list installed ones with `locale -a`. Install missing locales by running

```
sudo locale-gen da_DK.utf8
sudo update-locale
```

As described in [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/76013/how-do-i-add-locale-to-ubuntu-server). Lualatex will work then work fine, even with "weird" locales like `en_DK`, provided that it is installed.