# Installation error on Ubuntu

Tags: installing, ubuntu

On Ubuntu 20.04, my installation of texlive breaks down and produces the following error log. What does that mean and how can I fix it?

```
No pages of output.
Transcript written on pdflatex.log.
fmtutil [INFO]: log file copied to: /var/lib/texmf/web2c/pdftex/pdflatex.log
fmtutil [INFO]: /var/lib/texmf/web2c/pdftex/pdflatex.fmt installed.
fmtutil [ERROR]: running `luatex -ini   -jobname=luatex -progname=luatex luatex.ini </dev/null' return status: 1
fmtutil [ERROR]: cannot copy log luatex.log to: /var/lib/texmf/web2c/luatex
fmtutil [ERROR]: returning error due to option --strict
fmtutil [ERROR]: running `luatex -ini   -jobname=lualatex -progname=lualatex lualatex.ini </dev/null' return status: 1
fmtutil [ERROR]: cannot copy log lualatex.log to: /var/lib/texmf/web2c/luatex
fmtutil [ERROR]: returning error due to option --strict
fmtutil [ERROR]: running `luatex -ini   -jobname=dvilualatex -progname=dvilualatex dvilualatex.ini </dev/null' return status: 1
fmtutil [ERROR]: cannot copy log dvilualatex.log to: /var/lib/texmf/web2c/luatex
fmtutil [ERROR]: returning error due to option --strict
fmtutil [ERROR]: running `luatex -ini   -jobname=dviluatex -progname=dviluatex dviluatex.ini </dev/null' return status: 1
fmtutil [ERROR]: cannot copy log dviluatex.log to: /var/lib/texmf/web2c/luatex
fmtutil [ERROR]: returning error due to option --strict
fmtutil [INFO]: successfully rebuilt formats: 8
fmtutil [INFO]: failed to build: 4 (luatex/luatex luatex/lualatex luatex/dvilualatex luatex/dviluatex)
fmtutil [INFO]: total formats: 12
fmtutil [INFO]: exiting with status 4
```

Comment: Maybe you can run the first problematic line manually in a terminal (`luatex -ini   -jobname=luatex -progname=luatex luatex.ini`) and see what kind of errors you get?

Comment: `Unable to read environment locale: exit now.`

Comment: I suspect it is related to: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/374303/luatex-error-unable-to-read-environment-localeexit-now

Comment: my `LC_TIME` variable had an unusual value. Apparently that's enough to break those commands. Changing the time format (temporarily) fixed the issue.