# running luatex in with locale set to `en_US.UTF-8`: Unable to read environment locale: exit now?

Tags: luatex

I run lualatex in a process generated with a system call in Haskell. Lualatex stops with the error  message `Unable to read environment locale: exit now`. The file compiles with lualatex when run from a terminal. The locale is set to en_US-UTF-8 (verified by `locale`); I have installed all other locales to avoid any mixup as indicated in [another question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/374303/luatex-error-unable-to-read-environment-localeexit-now) and I have added in the file the recommended `%%% eval: (setenv "LANG" "de_DE.UTF-8")` there. All to no avail.

What else can I do?

I observed that the error message says

```
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
```

and the values are

```
LANG=en-US
LANGUAGE=en_US:en
LC_CTYPE="en-US"
```

i.e. the value to be set are `en-US` (with dash) and not `en_US` with underscore.

There seems some inference with the way I call the process; at least, one can say that `lualatex` is not resilient and does not produce a helpful error message (e.g. say what was found and what was expected).

Comment: Have you considered posting your query to a Haskell forum?

Comment: @user855443 When you verified your locale, did you run `locale` from Haskell or directly?

Comment: I did run `locale` from the command line - i will try it from a Haskell call. @Marcel Krüger: Thank you for the valuable suggestion!

Comment: I have not found an answer, but the error went away. I noticed that somewhere the locale was set to en-US (with dash, not underbar). while searching for the cause it disappeared.